# Scrape a PHP variable with Beautiful Soup, urllib2, and Python

Tags: php, python, html, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I am attempting to use Beautiful Soup and Python to scrape a PHP value from a website.

I also attempted to use the lxml library.

Is there a way to do it this way? Or should I use something different? Thanks in advance.

**Steps Followed**

1. Find nested HTML tag desired. In this case "320"
2. Parse HTML page.
3. Search for the first "div" tag.
4. Attempt to search all children of the "div" tag.
5. Output the entire HTML page to a text file.
6. Grep the desired "span" tag name.
7. Notice that the value is a PHP variable.

**xPath:**

```
//*[@id="monetary_offer_content"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/h3/span
```

**CSS Selector**

```
monetary_offer_content > div.monetary_offer > div.offers.clear > div > div.clearfix > h3 > span
```

**HTML:**

```
<span data-oldoffer="">320</span>
```

**After outputting the entire HTML page to a .txt file and then grepping the element name**:

```
| => cat text.txt | grep data-oldoffer
      <h3>$<span data-oldoffer><%= value['offer'] %></span></h3>
      <h3>$<span data-oldoffer><%= value['offer'] %></span></h3>
```

**Python Code**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
url="http://website_url.com"
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), "lxml")
print(soup)
```

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I belive this was gazelle.com on a specific product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the value is dynamically set via javascript in the browser. The page source you download with `urllib2` contains the initial HTML only.

What you can do is to fire up and control a real browser via [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/), sample:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "http://website_url.com"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(url)

elm = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#monetary_offer_content > div.monetary_offer > div.offers.clear > div > div.clearfix > h3 > span")))
print(elm.text)

driver.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure why I was downvoted. I feel like I can never ask a question without somebody downvoting it on S.O. I try to make the question as clear and presentable as possible. I try to research the question for hours before I post my own. Ugh. So frustrating. So when the browser renders the web page it will set the value every time, but if I use urllib2 it will only contain the initial HTML. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @Speakeasys I personally don't think your question deserves a downvote since it is clear, has a structure and shows your attempts, but that's just my opinion I guess.

Comment: Thank you very much. I hadn't known that I could even select the best answer. I always thought I wasn't able to do anything but ask questions because my reputation is so low.